# CSS button misaligning text in list

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see in this screenshot, the text becomes vertically unaligned (slightly higher) when a button is added. How can I avoid this? **(Bootstrap 5)**

[image: Unaligned text]

Here is the code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <h2 class="border-bottom border-dark pt-4">Roles</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <b>Roles</b>
        </div>

        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">Admins
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" type="button">View</button>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">Custom
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Edit</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: I should also have included the text in a span within the li for good measure

Comment: I made your "missing div" appear by formatting the code correctly. If you don't indent it with 4 spaces it will render as HTML and not be displayed as Code. So no bug, but rather the intended behaviour.

Comment: @cloned interesting I didn't know that, thank you!

Comment: @AmanSharma sorry, Bootstrap 5!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add class `align-items-center` to each `li`

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <h2 class="border-bottom border-dark pt-4">Roles</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <b>Roles</b>
        </div>

        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">Admins
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" type="button">View</button>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">Custom
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Edit</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you!! this was the fix, I believe I tried this earlier but was applying it to the <ul> not each <li> haha